# How can I get Google to index two pages for the same product with different categories?

Tags: duplicate-content, google-index

I have 2 pages that are very similar: same products but different categories.

I need both to be indexed by Google. How do I do it?

Comment: Google detects pages that are the same and chooses one to index.  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)  You need to differentiate the pages if you want them both indexed

Answer (score 1):

Based on everything that I know, you will have to rename at least one of the 2 products - despite the fact that everything is still the same except for the name - and I recommend doing this in such a way that is relevant to the underlying category.

For example, you are selling a hat that is unisex, but you want it to show in both mens and womens categories. For the sake of this example, let's name is "The Stack Hat."Therefore, you would have a "Men's Stack Hat" as well as a "Woman's Stack Hat". This example allowed us to take the exact same product, rename it, and ensure that it is unique and therefore will be visible within Google.

It is assumed that you would also rewrite the product description in such a way that it would prevent duplication. In the example above, "Men's" vs. "Woman's" would do the trick.

Comment: the page shows only 6 products, the rest is made of H1 (different) description of page (different), subtitle of product (different) and so on. only code of product are the same, but, again they're only 6 products. So why google skip my page? Is there a way to know if google skipped my page or it just hasn't still indexed it?

Comment: errors in my prev comment. what I meant is:
the 2 pages show only 6 products, the rest is made of H1 (different between pages) description of page (different between pages), subtitle of product (different between pages) and so on. only code of product are the same, but, again they're only 6 products. So why google skip one of my 2 pages? Is there a way to know if google skipped my page or it just hasn't still indexed it?

Comment: Absolutely. There are a several ways you could go about this. The easiest would be to simply to use an advanced search parameter using the google search function. Go to Google.com & search site:yourdomainname.com/your-page-name.html. If Google has indexed the page, it will show up. You can also use this for your entire domain by removing the subdirectory and/or page: site:yourdomainname.com.

Comment: But your best long-term solution is to create a Google Search Console account (if you have not already) and submit your sitemap. Upon processing the sitemap, Google will then indicate which pages have been indexed, as well as the number of pages which have been excluded.

Comment: I already have a search console. But I can see only the number of indexed and not indexed pages, not which page is not indexed :(

Comment: anyway I have a sitemap where I have 8 urls and 2 indexed. but If I try with site:mysite/thesepages all are visible in google search

Comment: You should definitely verify each site individually within Google Console, as well as submit a sitemap for *EACH* site you are operating.